# open text file in android emulator

Tags: android

How to open a text file in android.I am using android 1.5 emulator and eclipse ide.I try to push files to the device emulator.In Eclipse ide android file explorer has the text file and image files in the sdcard.In the Emulator Image files are in the Gallery.How can i see the text file in the android emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not come with a text editor. You will need to write one, or find one that is downloadable from outside of the market.